# JSF 2.2 taglib support in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

Eclipse Juno ships with support for JSF 2.0. I have configured my project to use the JSF Facet, so auto completion for tags works fine.

In JSF 2.2 there are several new tags, like the new Flow feature (xmlns:j="http://java.sun.com/jsf/flow").

I have put JSF 2.2.m05 on the classpath, but still Eclipse will not resolve the JSF 2.2 -> taglib descriptors.

How can I configure Eclipse to respect JSF 2.2 taglibs?

I suspect it reads the Eclipse Juno shipped JSF taglibs (JSF 2.1), hence it won't resolve any of the new tags.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: How are you referencing them in your file?  How are you testing that they're not respected?

Comment: In Project Facets -> Java Server Faces -> User Library, I have set up a library that points to the jsf-api and jsf-impl for JSF 2.2.m05.