# Update JSF 2.0 to JSF 2.2 in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2

I want to use some HTML5 tags in my project so I want to update my JSF version to 2.2 which supports HTML5 tags. Currently I'm using the JSF library [Eclipse downloads itself](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/JSFTools_tutorial_JSF20.html) with Eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 2.

I read a lot of different instructions on how to perform the update like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209498/jsf-2-2-taglib-support-in-eclipse-juno) one.

**The steps I went through:**
I downloaded the `jsf-impl-2.2.0-m05.jar` and `jsf-api-2.2.0-m05.jar` and moved them to `WEB-INF/lib` of my project.

Then I went to Properties/Project Facets/Java Server Faces and clicked on User Libraries, then I added a "New" one calling it "JSF 2.2", I added the two jars I downloaded to `lib` earlier. Once I added these I'm back to the User Library screen but I can't click on "Apply" because it's telling me:

```
Required class javax.faces.FactoryFinder does not exist in selected libraries.
```

I'm using this `faces-config.xml`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16131589/989919

Somehow I messed up and now I'm just seeing a:

```
HTTP Status 404
description The requested resource is not available.
```

If I try to access my index.xhtml.

There are error messages in the Eclipse console when I'm using the 2.0 version Eclipse downloaded.

```
Jun 23, 2013 9:52:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.39
Jun 23, 2013 9:52:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4823)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Jun 23, 2013 9:52:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Jun 23, 2013 9:52:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

and

```
Jun 23, 2013 9:52:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: Starting up MyFaces-package : myfaces-api in version : 2.0.2 from path : file:/Users/mediocre/Documents/Developement/Eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/WebEng_07/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-api-2.0.2.jar
Jun 23, 2013 9:52:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: Starting up MyFaces-package : myfaces-impl in version : 2.0.2 from path : file:/Users/mediocre/Documents/Developement/Eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/WebEng_07/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-impl-2.0.2.jar
Jun 23, 2013 9:52:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk not found.
Jun 23, 2013 9:52:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk12 not found.
Jun 23, 2013 9:52:55 PM org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your jars in the build path?
Check in eclipse, right click in the current project and go to properties->java build path->libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Probably move up your library on java build path->order and export tab.
On maven project for exemple, you need to move up maven dependencies or move down JSF librairies

Comment: An other solution is to register JSF 2.2 librairies on user library (windows->preferences->java->build path->user libraries->add , and add new JSF capabity to your project (select java server faces version under project property->project facets->java server faces)